# bash says "homebrew: command not found"

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew

I am new to OS X and was following a video and typed

```
export PATH="$HOME/opt/git/bin:$PATH"
```

I believe this messed up my path and I am not able to install MySQL now.

When I tried to install Homebrew I get

```
-bash: homebrew: command not found.
```

I tried restarting the terminal. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get the `export` line from?

First things first: Look into your home folder (e.g. open a Finder window). Is there really a folder called `opt` in there? If yes, something's really messed up. If no, your `export` command was just wrong, since there's no `opt` under `$HOME` (which is your user's home folder). `/opt` is typically at the root level of the file system.

Is there a folder called `/opt`? Open a Terminal and enter `ls /opt`. Does this directory exist? If yes, then you're probably using another package manager already and should not install Homebrew.

But even then, if `/opt` really exists, there shouldn't be `/opt/git/bin`.

If you really want to install a new version of Git, you can do that with:

- the [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/), which will install everything to `/usr/local/git/`
- through Homebrew with `brew install git`, see below, which will install the `git` command to `/usr/local/bin/`

---

To install Homebrew, you have to follow [the instructions](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation). There is no `homebrew` command. You also don't have to change your `PATH`.

You just have to copy and paste this to your Terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

This will install Homebrew, but make it available under the `brew` command. So to install MySQL through Homebrew, you'd enter:

```
brew install mysql
```